# How can I define a surjective ring homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_{22}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_7$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

How can I define a surjective ring homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_{22}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_7$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Not even a surjective group homomorphism.

The isomorphism theorem implies that image of a group homomorphism $G \to H$ of finite groups has size that divides the sizes of $G$ and $H$. When these sizes are coprime, the only possible group homomorphism is the trivial one.

Therefore, the only ring homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_{22}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_7$ is the zero map. If you insist that ring homomorphisms preserve $1$ then there are none.